# Existence and uniqueness of the solution to $dX_{t}=\left(2\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}>0\right\} }-1\right)\cos X_{t}dt+\cos X_{t}dW_{t}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\chi$ denotes an indicator variable and $W$ a Wiener process. What can we say about the solution of the following SDE:$$\begin{cases}
dX_{t}=\left(2\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}>0\right\} }-1\right)\cos X_{t}dt+\cos X_{t}dW_{t}\\
X_{0}=0
\end{cases}$$

Is there any solution? Is there any kind of uniqueness in the solution if at least one solution exists? If there is uniqueness, then what kind of uniqueness is this (uniqueness in distribution, in trajectories...)?

I have got this exercise in our course, but the coefficient function: $\left(2\chi_{\left\{ x>0\right\} }-1\right)\cos x$ is not even continuous, so it can't be Lipschitz continuous (here $\chi$ is the indicator function). My answer would be that we can't say anything about the solution, however I generated some paths numerically, and I didn't feel any strangeness in it.

Comment: It doesn't change the problem nor the question but notice that :$\left(2\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}>0\right\} }-1\right)$ is just the "sign" function, so that the sde can be rewritten as :  $$dX_{t}=|\cos X_{t}|dt+\cos X_{t}dW_{t}$$ and the coefficient is continuous.

Comment: @TheBridge Not quite... the SDE would be $dX_t = \mathrm{sgn}(X_t) \cos X_t dt + \cos X_t dW_t$. In particular, $ \mathrm{sgn}(X_t) \cos X_t \neq |\cos X_t |$.

Comment: you are right Jose

Comment: And it is not exactly the $sgn$ function, because at zero its value is $-1$ and not $0$.

Comment: If you had $\cos x + \varepsilon$, $\varepsilon > 0$ as the diffusion coefficient, then the SDE would have a unique strong solution due to a theorem by Zvonkin. Since $\cos x$ vanishes at some points it's not even clear to me that there is a weak solution.

Comment: @KapesMate Since this was an exercise in your course, did you ever get a solution to it?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly I didn't. This is why I asked it here :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the volatility coefficient, the solution is contained inside $I=(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and gets absorbed at the boundaries (because $X_{t\wedge \tau}$ also solves the SDE and so we apply uniqueness).

Within this interval we have $\sigma(x)=\cos(x)>0$ and within compact subsets $[-r,r,]\subset I$ we have bounded away drift $\sigma(x)>\epsilon_{r}>0$. So here we can apply standard SDE results such as in Revuz-Yor Chapter IX 1.14 corollary which allows for bounded drifts

[image]

to get existence and uniqueness in each $[-r,r]\subset I$.